# The iPhone could not be updated. An unknown error occurred (4013) - Is there still a way to solve?

Tags: ios, itunes, restore

Today my iPhone X got stuck at a logo-flash-loop. After searching for some information with Google I tried the "voldown+volup" restart way.

The infinite logo loop did stop but I still can't access my iPhone. I saw a screen like this:

[image]

I searched again and found that there is a way to update my iPhone software without erasing my data. It says that I just need to use iTunes on Mac to update the iOS software.

Which I think is very good. So I opened my iTunes on my Mac and it really tells me that there's an update (like 13.3.1).

After clicking some confirm buttons, I ran into this screen below.
[image]

After downloading the iOS package. And everything starts to move on. I saw an error like this:

[image]

What can I do now? What is trouble for me is not just data, pictures, but I have 2 of my bank apps on the iPhone which is super inconvenient to recover if I can't access them.

Comment: As your iTunes is updated, make sure whatever OS you have - try to get the full update (not need to be macOS Catalina too) but get all required supplementary updates. also, check your USB cable, try with a different ones.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you are using iTunes which is not available in the latest macOS Catalina. 
Please try the same with apple configurator 2. It might help.

This error might have occurred because your macOS is not up to date.

Comment: Really don't want to get updated to Catalina because I have Adobe Fireworks on this machine. But thanks so much, I will try to get another mac with Catalina installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Mac where you can make one last backup in case your iCloud backup is not current or even enabled, that is the first step.

Next is to get a completely updated Mac to see if it can update the device without erasing it.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201444

Follow the steps in order if at all possible. Even though you did some of the steps - the update of the software means it’s best to repeat those again once all the updates are ready for this specific 4013 error.